# django modelform display blank for null

Tags: python, django

In django model form, how to display blank for null values i.e prevent display of (None) on the form .Using postgresql, django 1.6.5. I do not wish to add space in the model instance for the allowed null values.

Answer (score 1):

By default, each Field class assumes the value is required, so if you pass an empty value – either `None` or the empty string `("")` – then `clean()` will raise a `ValidationError` exception:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> f = forms.CharField()
>>> f.clean('foo')
u'foo'
>>> f.clean('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValidationError: [u'This field is required.']
>>> f.clean(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValidationError: [u'This field is required.']
```

If a Field has `required=False` and you pass `clean()` an empty value, then `clean()` will return a normalized empty value rather than raising `ValidationError`. For `CharField`, this will be a Unicode empty string. For other Field classes, it might be `None`. (This varies from field to field.)

Like this:

```
>>> f = forms.CharField(required=False)
>>> f.clean('foo')
u'foo'
>>> f.clean('')
u''
>>> f.clean(None)
u''
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead I ended up using forms.HiddenInput() and did not display the field with null, which fits my case perfectly well!